# Use Angular Directive attributes in its template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I use the value of an attribute in a directive? My element looks like this:

```
<div class="tooltip-icon" 
  data-my-tooltip="click" 
  data-tooltip-title="foo" 
  data-tooltip-content="test content"></div>
```

I would like to use that in the template of my directive, which looks like this:

```
mainApp.directive('myTooltip',
    function() {

        // allowed event listeners
        var allowedListeners = ["click"];

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template:   '<div class="tooltip-title">...</div>' +
                        '<div class="tooltip-content">' +
                        '...</div>',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                if(allowedListeners.indexOf(attrs.myTooltip) != -1){
                    elm.bind(attrs.myTooltip, function(){
                        ...
                    });
                }

            }
        };
    }
);
```

Where the triple dots are there should be code, but I cannot figure out how to get the contents of the attrs object (`attrs.tooltipTitle`, etc) into that template.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can pull the attributes out and place them into the scope of the directive like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
directive('myTooltip', function ($log) {
    // allowed event listeners
    var allowedListeners = ["click"];
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template:   '<div class="tooltip-title">{{tooltipTitle}}</div>' +
                    '<div class="tooltip-content">' +
                    '{{tooltipContent}}</div>',
        scope: {
            tooltipTitle: '@tooltipTitle',
            tooltipContent: '@tooltipContent'
        },
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            if (allowedListeners.indexOf(attrs.myTooltip) != -1) {
                elm.bind(attrs.myTooltip, function () {
                    $log.info('clicked');
                });
            }

        }
    };
});
```

Here is  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/f3JL3/

Comment: As for the scope, are \@tooltipTitle and \@tooltipcontent pulling the content into the scope of this instance only, ie, can I have 2 tooltips on the same page and they won't overwrite eachothers title and content?

Comment: You should be able to have as many as you want on the page. It is pulling from the DOM attributes. You can find out more about how I did it here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directivedefinitionobject

Answer (score 2):

This question *has* already been answered, but I'm going to share my Angular code aswell, as this is one area where it's often useful to see a few working examples.

I have a few webpages, each with their own Angular controller, and I wanted a way to have **one** "Please Wait" popup on each page, which would appear when any of the pages called an HTTP GET or POST web service.

[image]

To do this, each of my webpages contains this line:

```
<please-wait message="{{LoadingMessage}}" ></please-wait>
```

...which is bound to a `$scope` in that page's controller...

```
$scope.LoadingMessage = "Loading the surveys...";
```

Here's the code for my `<please-wait>` directive:

```
myApp.directive('pleaseWait',  
    function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                message: '@message'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$on('app-start-loading', function () {
                    element.fadeIn(); 
                });
                scope.$on('app-finish-loading', function(){
                    element.animate({
                        top: "+=15px",
                        opacity: "0"
                    }, 500);
                });
            },
            template: '<div class="cssPleaseWait"><span>{{ message }}</span></div>'
        }
    });
```

Notice how it picks up the `message` attribute (`{{LoadingMessage}}` in this example) and can display its value in the directive's template.

(That's actually the only part of my answer which directly answers this question, but read on, for a few more tips'n'tricks...)

Now, the cool part is that each of my controllers calls an Angular data service whenever it wants to load or save any data from/to a web service.

```
   $scope.LoadAllSurveys = function () {
        DataService.dsLoadAllSurveys($scope).then(function (response) {
            //  Success
            $scope.listOfSurveys = response.GetAllSurveysResult;
        });
   }
```

The `dsLoadAllSurveys` function looks like this...

```
myApp.webServicesURL = "http://localhost:15021/Service1.svc";

myApp.factory('DataService', ['$http', 'httpPostFactory', 'httpGetFactory',
    function ($http, httpPostFactory, httpGetFactory) {

        var dsLoadAllSurveys = function (scope)
        {
            //  Load all survey records, from our web server
            var URL = myApp.webServicesURL + "/getAllSurveys";
            return httpGetFactory(scope, URL);
        }

        return {
            dsLoadAllSurveys: dsLoadAllSurveys
        }
    }]);
```

And, crucially, all "GET" web service calls go via the following function, which displays the Please Wait control for us... then makes it go away when the service has completed.

```
myApp.factory('httpGetFactory', function ($http, $q) {
    return function (scope, URL) {
        //  This Factory method calls a GET web service, and displays a modal error message if something goes wrong.
        scope.$broadcast('app-start-loading');          //  Show the "Please wait" popup

        return $http({
            url: URL,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        }).then(function (response) {
            scope.$broadcast('app-finish-loading');     //  Hide the "Please wait" popup
            if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                return response.data;
            } else {
                // invalid response
                return $q.reject(response.data);
            }
        }, function (errorResponse) {
            scope.$broadcast('app-finish-loading');     //  Hide the "Please wait" popup

            //  The WCF Web Service returned an error.  
            //  Let's display the HTTP Status Code, and any statusText which it returned.
            var HTTPErrorNumber = (errorResponse.status == 500) ? "" : "HTTP status code: " + errorResponse.status + "\r\n";
            var HTTPErrorStatusText = errorResponse.statusText;

            var message = HTTPErrorNumber + HTTPErrorStatusText;

            BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Error',
                message: message,
                buttons: [{
                    label: 'OK',
                    action: function (dialog) {
                        dialog.close();
                    },
                    draggable: true
                }]
            });

            return $q.reject(errorResponse.data);
        });
    };
});
```

What I love about this code is that this one function looks after displaying/hiding the "Please wait" popup, and if an error occurs, it also looks after displaying the error message (using the excellent [BootstrapDialog](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) library), before returning the error result back to the caller.

*Without* this factory function, each time one of my Angular controllers would call a web service, it would need to show, then hide, the "Please wait" control, and check for errors.

Now, I can just call my web service, and leave *it* to inform the user if something goes wrong, otherwise I can assume it's all worked, and process the results.

This allows me to have much simpler code.  Remember how I called that web service:

```
   DataService.dsLoadAllSurveys($scope).then(function (response) {
        //  Success
        $scope.listOfSurveys = response.GetAllSurveysResult;
    });
```

That code *looks* as though it's not doing any error-handling, whereas actually, it's all looked after behind the scenes in one place.

I'm still getting the hang of factories and data services with Angular, but  I think this is a stonking example of how they can help.

Hope this made sense, and helps.