# How to display wait message in AngularJS while data loading?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS and trying to find the way how to display wait message while data loading? I mean data starts loading, display message and remove it when data loading is done.

I've searched the internet but haven't found anything I need...

Comment: In case you want to show a loading indicator for web service calls, there is also a way to intercept http calls.
There are some blog posts on how to implement such an interceptor. A good one is this: http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2013/01/02/using-response-interceptors-to-show-and-hide-a-loading-widget/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
<div ng-if="data.dataLoading">
    Loading...
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.data.dataLoading = true;

return someService.getData().then(function (results) {                    
    ...
}).finally(function () {
    $scope.data.dataLoading = false;
});
```

Comment: This approach fits very well. Thanks.

Comment: Problem: it will show the "Loading..." message even if server returned you empty list or null.

Comment: if I do this inside ng-click handler, and do `this.data.dataLoading = true`, it does'nt update the view.

Answer (score 5):

Depends from where you're loading the data. One solution I used was to create a LoadingService

```
app.factory('LoadingService', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        loading : function(message) {
             $rootScope.loadingMessage = message;
        },
        loaded : function() {
             $rootScope.loadingMessage = null;
        }
    }
}).controller('FooController', function($scope,$http,LoadingService) {

   $scope.loadSomeData = function() {
       LoadingService.loading('Data is loading');

       $http.get('/data').finally(function() {
            LoadingService.loaded();
       });
   };
});
```

Since I had only one place where the message was being displayed I could use RootScope to handle this. If you want to have a loading message multiple times you could write a directive also to handle this like Codezilla posted

Answer (score 1):

Edit: does not work on version 1.3.0 . Use request/response interceptors.

If you want to listen to all requests globally and display a loading widget whenever there's a request pending, you can count the requests using [request/response transformers](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#description_transforming-requests-and-responses). You simply add a counter and increase on a new request and decrease it on response. I use a provider for that:

```
$httpProvider
  .defaults
  .transformRequest
  .push(function(data) {
      requestNotificationProvider
      .fireRequestStarted(data);
      return data;
});
```

And the same for `transformResponse`. Then the same provider holds the information on how many requests are pending and you can use them in a directive. You can read (& copy/paste the code) a full blog post on that here:
http://www.kvetis.com/2014/01/angularjs-loading-widget.html There's a working demo in attached.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered this question in [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279214/391605), but here's a recap of what I did.

If you style your code correctly, and make sure all calls to a web service pass through **one** particular `factory` function, then you can make that `factory` function handle showing and hiding your "Please Wait" popup.

Here's the `factory` function which I use to call all of my GET web services:

```
myApp.factory('httpGetFactory', function ($http, $q) {
    return function (scope, URL) {
        //  This Factory method calls a GET web service, and displays a modal error message if something goes wrong.
        scope.$broadcast('app-start-loading');          //  Show the "Please wait" popup

        return $http({
            url: URL,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        }).then(function (response) {
            scope.$broadcast('app-finish-loading');     //  Hide the "Please wait" popup
            if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                return response.data;
            } else {
                // invalid response
                return $q.reject(response.data);
            }
        }, function (errorResponse) {
            scope.$broadcast('app-finish-loading');     //  Hide the "Please wait" popup

            //  The WCF Web Service returned an error.  
            //  Let's display the HTTP Status Code, and any statusText which it returned.
            var HTTPErrorNumber = (errorResponse.status == 500) ? "" : "HTTP status code: " + errorResponse.status + "\r\n";
            var HTTPErrorStatusText = errorResponse.statusText;

            var message = HTTPErrorNumber + HTTPErrorStatusText;

            BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Error',
                message: message,
                buttons: [{
                    label: 'OK',
                    action: function (dialog) {
                        dialog.close();
                    },
                    draggable: true
                }]
            });

            return $q.reject(errorResponse.data);
        });
    };
});
```

This would get called like this:

```
myApp.webServicesURL = "http://localhost:15021/Service1.svc";

var dsLoadAllEmployees = function (scope)
{
     //  Load all survey records, from our web server
     $scope.LoadingMessage = "Loading Employees data...";

     var URL = myApp.webServicesURL + "/loadAllEmployees";
     return httpGetFactory(scope, URL);
}
```

Here's the "Please wait" control which I use on each page..

```
<please-wait message="{{LoadingMessage}}" ></please-wait>
```

... and its code looks like this...

```
myApp.directive('pleaseWait',  
    function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                message: '@message'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$on('app-start-loading', function () {
                    element.fadeIn(); 
                });
                scope.$on('app-finish-loading', function(){
                    element.animate({
                        top: "+=15px",
                        opacity: "0"
                    }, 500);
                });
            },
            template: '<div class="cssPleaseWait"><span>{{ message }}</span></div>'
        }
    });
```

Using this structure, any of my Angular controllers can load data from a web service in just a few lines, and leave the factory to look after showing/hiding the "Please wait" message and to display any errors which occur:

```
   $scope.LoadAllSurveys = function () {
        DataService.dsLoadAllSurveys($scope).then(function (response) {
            //  Success
            $scope.listOfSurveys = response.GetAllSurveysResult;
        });
   }
```

Nice, hey ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is the correct way, but I put on my template

```
 <img id="spinner" ng-src="images/spinner.gif" ng-if="!data" >
 <div ng-repeat="repo in repos | orderBy: repoSortOrder">...</div>
```