# Angular ngShow is not removing tag style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

This is my js:

```
(function () {
    angular.module("profile.view", [])
            .controller("ViewController", ["$scope", function (scope) {
                scope.profile = {{ profile_json|raw }};
            }]);

    angular.module("profileApp", ["profile.view"]);

    angular.bootstrap(document, ["profileApp"]);
})();
```

and my html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="loading" ng-if="false">Loading ....</div>
    <div ng-controller="ViewController" style="display: none" ng-show="true">
            some text
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why angular is not removing "display:none" when it is loaded ?

Comment: why are you doing that?

Comment: i'm hidding the div content while angular is not loaded yet. When it loaded, then loading div is get hidden. but other div should be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS class onto the element. The .ng-hide CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the display style to none (using an !important flag).

So it doesn't edit the `display: none` because it isn't supposed to edit it.

Also, I suggest you to read a guidestyle, like [this](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide) one. 
And if you want to have a loading message, please take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358431/how-to-display-wait-message-in-angularjs-while-data-loading) question.

Answer (score 3):

when we make **ng-show=false**, angular add (external) css like `display: none !important`. And if wee make **ng-show=true** it removes that css.

And whatever we make change (the value of ng-show), it always remain **display: none** at the html. So it always remain hide. Because inline has the higher priority than both internal and external css. So, to show the element we have to remove the inline css from the element.